# Twilio Notify body/title text only displaying the name of the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-api

I was reading over the documentation for the `body` text for Twilio Notify.

> (optional for all except Alexa) Indicates the notification body text. Translates to data.twi_body for FCM and GCM, aps.alert.body for APNS, Body for SMS and Facebook Messenger and request.message.data for Alexa. For SMS either this, body, or the media_url attribute of the Sms parameter is required. For Facebook Messenger either this parameter or the body attribute in the FacebookMessenger parameter is required.

I'm sending both a title and body in my notification, but neither appears on my android device due to the `twi_` prefix. Is there any way I can display something other than my app name in the push notification?

For reference, here is my push notification code.

```
class PushNotification
def self.new_order(order)
    @order = order

    # find the nearby drivers
    @drivers = Driver.within(20, :origin => [@order.pickup_address.lat, @order.pickup_address.lng]).where(updated_at: 2.hours.ago.. Time.now)

    @drivers.each do |driver|
        $twilio.notify.services(ENV['TWILIO_SERVICE_SID']).notifications.create(title: "New Order Nearby", body: "Order ##{@order.id} is waiting for a driver.", identity: driver.id.to_s)
    end 
end 

def self.update_order(order)
    @order = order

    unless @order.driver_id.nil?
        $twilio.notify.services(ENV['TWILIO_SERVICE_SID']).notifications.create(title: "Order Updated", body: "Order ##{@order.id} has been updated. Please refresh.", identity: @order.driver_id.to_s)
    end
end 
end
```

Comment: You need to capture the incoming push notification and build your own alert out of it. Check out the [Twilio Notify Android quick start app](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/notifications-quickstart-android/blob/69ab7db60deb8e428bdcf368e3595897e1cfd591/app/src/main/java/com/twilio/notify/quickstart/fcm/NotifyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L33) to see how it's been done there. (I'd give a more in depth answer, but I'm not an Android dev, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$twilio.notify.services(ENV['TWILIO_SERVICE_SID']).notifications.create(title: title, 
        body: body, 
        identity: id.to_s,
        fcm: {
            notification:
            {
                title: title,
                body: body
            }
    })
```

After reading through the docs again, I tried this and it worked. The only issue is the app icon is blank.